# Clicking Button with Selenium (Python) has no effect

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get Block Deals data from [NSE site](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/bulk.htm). I have already Automated the process of selecting 
 1) Selecting Block Deals from dropdown menu.
 2) Clicking on Radio Button and Sending Dates (from and to).
 But When I try to click on "Get Data" button nothing is happening. Even though the button element can be located and output shows the button has been clicked, there seems to be no effect at all.
 [image]

Element marked in the image:-

```
<p>
<img onclick="document.getElementById('submitMe').click()" id="get" src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif" style="margin-left: 20px;" class="getdata-button">  
<input type="button" style="display:none" onclick="submitData();" id="submitMe" tabindex="9" value="Get Results">
</p>
```

I've tried many methods like: 

 X_path of above element: "/html/body/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQvvC.png)/div[3]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQvvC.png)/div[1](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/bulk.htm)/div[4]/div[1](https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/bulk.htm)/div/form/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQvvC.png)/div[3]/p/img"

```
1) driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/p/img").click()
2) # Clicking with ActionChains
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/p/img")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
3) driver.execute_script("javascript:'get'")
4) driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('get').click()")
5) button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/p/img")))  
button .click()
```

But None of the above seems to click the button and get the data on the page.
My Code:-

```
# Select Block Deal from drop down
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dataType']/option[2]").click()

# Radio Button
if driver.find_element_by_id("rdDateToDate").get_attribute("type") == "radio":
    print("Element is a Radio button")
else:
    print("Element is not a Radio button")

radioElement = driver.find_element_by_id("rdDateToDate")
radioElement.click()

# From Date
from_date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fromDate")
from_date.clear()
time.sleep(2)
month = "01"
year = "2019"
day = "01"
from_date.send_keys("{day}-{month}-{year}".format(day = day, month = month, year = year))

#To Date
to_date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#toDate")
to_date.clear()
time.sleep(2)
month = "12"
year = "2019"
day = "31"
to_date.send_keys("{day}-{month}-{year}".format(day = day, month = month, year = year))

# Clicking at random at Y = 300
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(to_date, 200,0)
action.click()
action.perform()

## Clicking at Get Data Button
????????
```

Comment: your code is working fine , if you hv check even manual click is not working on the target button

Comment: Yes, does that mean they are using the bot manager that is causing this problem? Is there any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending key...

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/p/img")))  
button .send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Some cases of radio button and you may need to use action chain with sending space

```
xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/p/img'
your_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(your_element).send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```

Comment: Hi Hitesh Kumar, I tried both of the above listed method by you, but it didn't help. Sending key gave me "
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable" as error while Sending Space had no effect just like other used method mentioned in the question.

Comment: if you are ok share all steps of code in your question